# Angular, Error: First argument contains NaN in property

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I'm making a simple calculation formula to calculate percentage. But i got an error that said `First argument contains NaN in property 'percent.percentKey.percentMale`. I'm using Angular and Typescript with Angularfire to store data to the database. I defined the properties in a class.

```js
//app.ts
export class App {
  $key: string;
  gender: string;
  male: number = 0;
  female: number = 0;
  percentMale: number = 0;
  percentFemale: number = 0;
}


//app.service.ts
insertdata(data: App) {
  this.dataList.push({
    gender: data.gender,
  });

  if (data.gender == 'Male') {
    //this.male ++;
    data.male = data.male++
  } else if (data.gender == 'Female') {
    //this.female ++;
    data.female = data.female++
  }

  data.percentMale = data.male / (data.male + data.female) * 100
  console.log('male', data.male + '%');

  data.percentFemale = data.female / (data.male + data.female) * 100
  console.log('female', data.female + '%');
  
  console.log('1', data.percentMale); //it returns NaN
  console.log('2', data.percentFemale); //it returns NaN

  this.percentList.update("percentKey", {
    percentMale: data.percentMale,
    percentFemale: data.percentFemale
  })
}
```

I already import the class in service and call the `insertdata` function in component.ts like `this.AppService.insertpertanyaan(this.AppService.selectedpertanyaan);`.
Can anyone help me, please? Please let me know if more snippets are needed. Thank you.

Comment: Could there be a division by zero? Maybe `data.percentMale + data.female` is zero. You can log that value to the console.

Comment: i updated my code

Comment: Is your problem that `data.percentMale` is `NaN`?

Comment: it is still returns error `First argument contains NaN in property 'percent.percentKey.percentMale`

Comment: You can check with `console.log("data.percentMale", data.percentMale);` before `this.percentList.update(...)`.

Comment: I put console log and it returns `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines are problematic:

```
data.male = data.male++;
data.female = data.female++;
```

They should be:

```
data.male++;
data.female++;
```

When you use the postfix increment operator, `x++`, the value of x is incremented but the expression returns the previous value of x. When you do

```
x = x++;
```

x is first incremented, and then its previous value is assigned to x. As a consequence, x is back to its original value.

Comment: Thanks for helping :D

Comment: If i may ask one more question Mr.ConnorsFan, why when i reload the page or localhost, and insert data again, the value of percentMale and percentFemale become 0 again. For example i insert a new Male, it becomes 1 for male and 0 for female while there are already data in database.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but I suppose that you need to get the previous numbers from the database before adding to them.